# How to decrypt message gost2001

Tags: encryption, openssl, saml, gost3410

How to decrypt message:

```
algorithm="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:cpxmlsec:algorithms:transport-gost2001
```

?

File ENC_KEY:

```
MIGkMCgEIIL21aL9mNsYkPGux4Ywv+0Jh1gn6AYQHgsE9lyPaNi/BARz3b+ooHgGByqFAwICHwGgYzAcBgYqhQMCAhMwEgYHKoUDAgIjAQYHKoUDAgIeAQNDAARA3Xp8QDVUYjezeCDa9zzV3Mo2xK4gxc0vJ8/5yu6Zn5bpTZTTEDty7K9XcWSQRrOQdT7hRSV1osk4EJY9yI9k0gQIaIxb+7AUBFQ=
```

Decrypt:

```
    openssl enc -d -A -base64 -in ENC_KEY -out ENC_KEY.DER
    openssl smime -decrypt -engine gost -binary -noattr -inform PEM -in ENC_KEY.DER -out KEY.DER -inkey KEY.PEM
    engine "gost" set.
    Error reading S/MIME message
    139932807476880:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: PKCS7
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used the `-inform PEM` option to tell `openssl smime` to parse `ENC_KEY.DER` as a PEM file.  `ENC_KEY.DER` is not in PEM format; it is in DER format.  The error message indicates that it is failing to parse a PEM header.

You must change `-inform PEM` to `-inform DER`.

Comment: /opt/openssl/apps/openssl smime -decrypt -engine gost -binary -noattr -inform DER -in ENC_KEY.DER -out KEY.DER -inkey KEY.PEM 
engine "gost" set.
Error reading S/MIME message
139689802765968:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1180:
139689802765968:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:744:
139689802765968:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:676:Field=type, Type=PKCS7

Comment: OK, your DER isn't a PKCS7 object.  The object looks like a key wrapped using a GOST ECC algorithm, along with algorithm parameters and the public key used.  I must note that your `openssl enc -d` invocation does not decrypt anything, it merely decode the base64 of `ENC_KEY`.  But I am not familiar with GOST and can render no additional guidance at this time.